# Differential application of CSS styles to html elements

Tags: css

I want to apply margin-top: 45px only for small screens such as phones and tablets. The following is my code:

```
 @x-large: ~"only screen and (min-width: 1201px)";
 @large: ~"only screen and (max-width : 1200px)";
 @medium: ~"only screen and (max-width : 992px)";
 @small: ~"only screen and (max-width : 480px)";
 @x-small: ~"only screen and (max-width : 320px)";

 #myPanel {
  @media @small {
    margin-top: 45px !important;
  }

  @media @x-small {
    margin-top: 45px !important;
  }

  @media @tablet {
    margin-top: 45px !important;
  }

  @media @x-large {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }

  @media @large {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  }
```

The problem is when I switch to desktop size too the style is applied. I have to use !important, otherwise it doesn't apply to small screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to make it work using @media query. Instead, I have resolved it using jquery.

```
jQuery code:
    window.addEventListener("resize", resolvePanels);
    window.addEventListener("load", resolvePanels);
    function resolvePanels(e){
        var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
        if (viewportWidth < 1025) {
            $("#myPanel").removeClass("noTopMargin").addClass("hasTopMargin");
        }
        else {
            $("#myPanel").removeClass("hasTopMargin").addClass("noTopMargin");
        } 
    }

CSS code
    .noTopMargin {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .hasTopMargin {
        margin-top: 45px;
    }
```

Comment: Essentially, during both the window load and resize events, the "resolvePanels(e)" function will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add.

```
@media @small {
  margin-top: 45px;
}
@media @x-large {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```